# ASP.NET Read individual values from a custom seperated row in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, sqldatareader

I store values that i save through a form in a database column named 'Properties' like:

```
value1#||#value2#||#value3#||#value4
```

The question is how to retrieve for example 'value2' from this string when using 'For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows'.

Using '`row("Properties")` obviously returns:  `value1#||#value2#||#value3#||#value4`.

How to construct something with a split function to retrieve the specific value (ex. value2)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `split("#||#")` to split the string by values. In your case to get value2 you would do:

```
String[] splitValues = row("Properties").ToString().Split(new String[] {"#||#"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
String value2 = splitValues[1];
```

Comment: A couple of minor edits required. Split should be with a capital S. Also if passing a string array to Split the StringSplitOptions parameter is required. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/tabh47cf.aspx

Comment: Thanks! 

It returns this error:
BC30311: Value of type '1-dimensional array of String' cannot be converted to 'Char' for the first line of code.

Comment: @MarcellinoBommezijn fixed. I'm writing it from the top of my head, let's hope that it is ok now :)

Comment: @nmat The adjusted code returns:
BC30311: Value of type '1-dimensional array of String' cannot be converted to 'String'.

Comment: @Marcellino Bommezijn Did you add the brackets to the variable declaration? `String[] splitValues`. If so, the problem must be with row("Properties"). Confirm that row("Properties") returns the value of a single cell from your table

Comment: @nmat Yes, that seems the trouble. I need to review my data access to include this column. Thanks for your swift solution! Appreciate it!

Comment: @nmat To confirm: the solution works like a charm. The problem was a stored procedure that didn't had the column in it's SELECT statement.